# Toric variety corresponding to coordinate axes in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry, toric-varieties

I have just learned how to construct a toric variety from a fan and I am a bit confused. Let $\Sigma$ be the fan that consists of the coordinate axes in $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. $\Sigma = \{ \sigma_0, \sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3, \sigma_4 \}$, where $\sigma_0=\{ (0,0) \}$, $\sigma_1=$Cone$(e_1)$, $\sigma_2=$Cone$(e_2)$, $\sigma_3=$Cone$(-e_1)$, and $\sigma_4=$Cone$(-e_2)$.

What is the toric variety corresponding to this fan?

Denote the coordinate ring of a variety $X$ by $A(X)$ and denote the affine toric variety corresponding to a cone $\sigma$ by $U_{\sigma}$. Is the following true?

- $A(U_{\sigma_1})=\mathbb{C}[y,y^{-1}]$
- $A(U_{\sigma_2})=\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]$
- $A(U_{\sigma_3})=\mathbb{C}[y,y^{-1}]$
- $A(U_{\sigma_4})=\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]$

If so, how do I glue these and what is the corresponding variety? I know that each cone in $\Sigma$ intersects only at $\sigma_0$, so I will be gluing along $(\mathbb{C}^{\ast})^2$. I need help doing this example explicitly. Thanks.

Comment: $A(U_{\sigma_1})$ should be $\mathbb{C}[x,y,y^{-1}]$, right?

Comment: You can try first understand what you will get if you take the complete fan. And then try to figure out what will change if you cut out the four open quadrants.

Comment: I know if you have the complete fan, you get $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$. I just realized that I computed the dual cones incorrectly.

Comment: Ok, each quadrant corresponds to a $T$-invariant point in your variety, you can check by explicit computation on each local patch to find out the missing four points are $(0\text{ or} \infty,0 \text{or }\infty)$, so the variety you are looking for is $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ with the above four points removed.